# Angular 4 + web pack + spring mvc (not boot) integration and deployment on tomcat

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

Recently I learnt Angular 4 and want to use it for my Spring MVC web application.

I can use both separately but struggling to put it together as run it as a single application with spring security in place.

Could someone please advise how should I achieve it.
All examples on the internet are working with Spring boot and as a separate module.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use spring-boot? That typically is the way to execute your application with spring nowadays, and is straight-forward too.

Comment: Hi Peter, I don't want to use Spring boot coz I don't want to change my deployment process and want to keep it same as my other projects.   As pr my knowledge there is a different process for deploying spring boot application using Jenkins on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set Angular CLI's build target to "target/classes/static" and then tell Spring to serve resources from there (Spring Boot does this automatically).

More detailed (when using Maven):

1. Create 3 Maven modules: backend (with your Java app), frontend (with your Angular app), webapp (referencing both as dependency)
2. In frontend change "outDir" in `.angular-cli.json` to "target/classes/static"
3. In frontend use [Maven Frontend Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) to call `npm install` / `npm run build`
4. In your webapp module [add a Spring resource handler](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) for classpath:/static

You can do this all in one module as well but I prefer to separate frontend and backend.

You can see our working example here (using Spring Boot): https://github.com/porscheinformatik/angular-spring-heroes